# Point existing EBS to new EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, amazon-ami

I have an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 11.04 with EBS attached, now I am planning to move to ***Amazon Linux AMI 2013.09.1***

Can I just launch new instance and map existing EBS is that enough or is there any other steps I need to follow.

Comment: Are you talking about the root EBS volume, or an additional one that just has data?

Comment: I am talking about the root EBS volume...

Comment: Then you can't do this. The root EBS volume contains the operating system. If you launch an Amazon Linux instance and replace its root volume with your Ubuntu root volume, it'll just be Ubuntu again.

Comment: ho.. then I have to launch new instance with Amazon Linux and move the files?

Comment: Yes. In the future, consider a configuration management system.